# Intercept or wrap printf calls for better logging

Tags: c++, logging, printf

I have a 3rd party code which is full of `printf`s and `perror`s. I want to get all that output and put it in some logging solution, in my case `spdlog`. I compile the 3rd party code myself, so patching the sources a bit is not a problem, but finding&replacing every occurrence of `printf` would be terrible and unmaintainable. Is there a way to do it in more general manner?

Comment: Would adding `-Dprintf=my_logging_function` to your compile-line be considered too evil?  :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner yes, writing `#define printf(...) something(...)` would be my last resort

Comment: Would it work to link in a translation unit defining your own `printf` and `perror`?

Comment: @PaulSanders I've no idea if it would work, that's why I asked a question :)

Comment: Neither have I, but surely worth trying

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with "redefine library function" approach in the end. Be advised though, ISO C considers this to be an UB. Also, you need to redefine `puts` as well, as compiler might replace some `printf` calls with `puts`.

```cpp
    extern "C" int puts(const char *str) {
        // put stuff in logger
    }

    extern "C" int printf(const char *format, ...) {
        std::va_list args, args2;
        va_start(args, format);
        va_copy(args2, args);
        int n = std::vsnprintf(nullptr, 0, format, args);
        va_end(args);
        auto str = std::make_unique<char[]>(n + 1);
        std::vsnprintf(str.get(), n + 1, format, args2);
        va_end(args2);
        puts(str.get()); // generally incorrect, since puts should append \n
        return 0;
    }

    extern "C" void perror(const char *s) {
        const char *colon;
        if (s == nullptr || *s == '\0') {
            s = colon = "";
        } else {
            colon = ": ";
        }
        printf("%s%s%s", s, colon, std::strerror(errno));
    }
```